# cannot access php file via url

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to access the file index.php through url.

```
 http://localhost:3000/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php.
```

Yesterday everything was working fine but today it gives me an error saying:

> "The requested resource
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php was not found on this
> server.".

The php file is in the location indicated by the url and it has not been moved.
Any help apprciated.
Thank you.

I've checked the folder htdocs and the file is there. I have created another php file with the same directory and the error is the same despite everything working fine yesterday.

Comment: try accessing http://localhost/index.php unless you have changed default port.

Comment: thank you it works now, but why does the url I used yesterday not work anymore?

Comment: How should we know? Probably something got reconfigured, but we don't know what you were doing yesterday, or what has changed, or anything else about your environment.

Comment: http://localhost in the URL is  equivalent to the complete path to htdocs folder, wherever it is. @SureshKamrushi, please put your solution in the answer filed, so this question will appear as answered.